# order of items in control[] array of a window

Tags: powerbuilder

In the windows there is a control[] array with the controls there are in the window.
does somebody knows what is the algorithm of the order of controls in that control[] array?.
There are times that that order is changed in developmen mode and I do not why. I have a big problem with it

please help

Comment: I can't confirm it for sure, I think it should be the "tab order", I'm not sure, you can do an "Edit Source" of the window and search for "this.Control[" I hope that gives you a clue.

Comment: Imho I think taborder isn´t the algorithm. Thank you for your interest

Comment: I don't see why the array order would matter. If you explained what you are trying to do you might get a good answer.

Comment: Hi Roland. I am using the PFCs  and the order of update objects is ipo_tempupdateobjects[],ipo_updateobjects[] and at last  the window Control []. If you ar not using PFCs it does not matter . Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

The control array in a powerbuilder visual object container (userobject, window, etc) is maintained as controls are created and destroyed, in the internal create and destroy events. These are usually in the order in which you placed the controls on the container. So for example if we look at the source code (rightclick the object in the system tree and choose 'Edit Source', or export to a src file) of a window called 'w_my_window' where I created two commandbuttons and a datawindow:

```
on w_my_window.create
int iCurrent
call super::create
this.cb_1=create cb_1
this.cb_2=create cb_2
this.dw_1=create dw_1
iCurrent=UpperBound(this.Control)
this.Control[iCurrent+1]=this.cb_1
this.Control[iCurrent+2]=this.cb_2
this.Control[iCurrent+3]=this.dw_1
end on

on w_my_window.destroy
call super::destroy
destroy(this.cb_1)
destroy(this.cb_2)
destroy(this.dw_1)
end on
```

Note that controls can be created and destroyed at other times in other events and functions if you code that way (ie dynamically creating controls using Create/OpenUserObject), and doing this will affect the control array as well.

Note also that the control array is built upon what happened in the ancestor, and descendants will continue to build on this control array.

For clarity, none of this applies to objects inside a datawindow.